# Can a stock ECM be modified to function with some modules disconnected

Tags: vw, engine-theory, diy

Engine in question: VOLKSWAGEN PASSAT 2015 - 2.0L, (VIN V, 5TH DIGIT, DIESEL), (ENGINE ID CVCA)

I hope to buy a rear-end collision Passat with this engine, and use as many parts as I can in a custom locost frame with a fiberglass replica of a lotus 11 body.

This engine of this car, mentioned at top, has a computer module connected to transmission and emissions modules. I will be using these modules, but not any of the other modules in the car that could potentially be connected to the modules I need. Does the ECM and related components need to be re-flashed in order to function without the modules I will be removing?

Comment: Not certain what you are asking.  What do you mean "run engine outside a car" ?

Comment: As long as you have fuel, air, and compression, a diesel engine will run. You'll need a fuel pump to get the fuel in and a 'starter' to initialize compression (could be an impact driver on the crankshaft, or a traditional flywheel type starter). For a modern engine like the one you mentioned in your question, you'll need some kind of engine management system as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? At the moment this is likely to get closed as "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad" - We can tell you how to run the engine outside of the car (that bit is easy), but I can't logically connect that with your stated goal...

Comment: Do I need to add more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Engine ECU can be reprogrammed so it will run properly without the need to connect any other ecu/module.

The ECU in question is a EDC17 there are pros and cons with this, the con being the flash and eeprom files are massive but the pro is that no soldering is required as it is programmed 'on the bench'.

The ecu firmware / memory contents can be modified in such a way that all you need to do is supply the wiring loom with a permanent live, ignition live, start signal and ground and the engine will run. There is no need for any other control module or aftermarket ecu etc.

As for sensors and emissions equipment, the EGR valve, DPF and associated sensors can all be removed provided the ECU is programmed accordingly, both pre and post the emission recall.

I have programmed many EDC17/MED17 ECUs to remove the EGR, DPF, Immobilser, fault codes and various unwanted sensors and actuators for both engine conversions and extreme modifications so I can confirm it is possible. Any good tuner should be able to everything you require.

As well as modifying the firmware/flash file for the above it can also be modified to make it more reliable, 'idiot proof' and less sensitive to errors.

Comment: Is it possible to leave the emissions and transmission modules attached while removing the others?

Comment: Yes you can leave as much or as little connected as you wish. I'm guessing you have a auto?

Comment: Thanks again, but I do not know what you mean by auto. If this stack is anything like stack overflow, we should move conversation elsewhere. My email is anyone7000@gmail.com if you want to know more about my project.

Answer (score 1):

passing inspection implies you can license it.  As for the rest, you need, on modern-ish cars, the engine computer, fuel pump, and body wiring  harness.  The sensors are "nice-to-haves" but wouldn't stop it running, except perhaps the map sensor.  You of course also need all parts of the cooling system.

More modern cars make this harder and have encoded ignition and body computers requiring you to keep all that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get aftermarket engine management systems which should avoid all the body and security module issues.

This may mean getting matching sensors if the original ones don’t match.

One example is : http://www.emeraldm3d.com/

Another is : http://pe-ltd.com

Comment: The original question was asked poorly. I would really appreciate it if you took the time to look at the revised version